# .NET Core DI Logger on Console app not logging to Console

Tags: .net, logging, dependency-injection, .net-core

I've got a .NET Core console app. Pretty simple. At this point the goal was just to get DI and Configuration integrated. However, the `LogDebug` isn't logging to the console.

What could I have possibly done wrong here?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var topic = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RECEIVER_TOPIC");
        var entity = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RECEIVER_ENTITY");

        //setup our DI
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging()
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        //configure console logging
        serviceProvider
            .GetService<ILoggerFactory>()
            .AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);

        var logger = serviceProvider
            .GetService<ILoggerFactory>()
            .CreateLogger<Program>();
        logger.LogDebug($"Starting application. Topic: {topic}. Entity: {entity}.");

        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    static IConfigurationRoot GetConfiguration()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

## Update 1

I added the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug` NuGet package, and modified the `serviceProvider` initialization to append the `AddDebug` like so:

```
serviceProvider
    .GetService<ILoggerFactory>()
    .AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug)
    .AddDebug();
```

But it's not even logging to the `Debug` window.

Answer (score 9):

Got it working. I think the key was that I wasn't yet clear that concretes needed to be registered because I thought the extension was registering the concretes.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var topic = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RECEIVER_TOPIC");
        var entity = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RECEIVER_ENTITY");

        // Create service collection
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);

        // Create service provider
        var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        var logger = serviceProvider
            .GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>()
            .CreateLogger<Program>();
        logger.LogDebug($"Starting application. Topic: {topic}. Entity: {entity}.");

        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        // Add logging
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
        serviceCollection.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder
            .AddConsole()
            .AddDebug()
            .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug));

        // Build configuration
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
            .Build();

        // Add access to generic IConfigurationRoot
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton(configuration);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. To make this work I also needed to import `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`, `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`

Comment: Looks like the appsettings is ignored here. I tried this code, set the default loglevel to Error and it still logged it out when I called LogDebug. Might have to dive into the ASP.NET Core code to see what they are doing there.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into the same exact problem, saw your answer, but did not understand why 'AddDebug()' was necessary. Removing it though stops the logger from logging to console. See [Logging to Console with DI in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59575156/logging-to-console-with-di-in-c-sharp) if interested. My guess is that Console logger spins off a separate thread and tries to aggregate logs and flush on timer to not be as intrusive. The Debug logger logs immediately, but I only wanted one. Switching to having an App class with async Run() method solves all problems.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to chip in with a revised ConfigureServices method which makes use of the logging section in an appsetting.json file.

First, I added an appsettings.json which looks like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

The, my ConfigureServices method:

```
    static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        // Build configuration
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
            .Build();

        // Add logging
        serviceCollection.AddLogging(config =>
        {
            // clear out default configuration
            config.ClearProviders();

            config.AddConfiguration(configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            config.AddDebug();
        });
    }
```

Note, no need to add `ILogger` and `ILoggerFactory` to the `ServiceProvider`.

I believe this is handled in the `AddLogging` extension method.

Comment: This requires `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` nuget

Answer (score 0):

Add logging.AddDebug(); works for me.
Thanks a lot!

```
.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.AddConsole();
                    logging.AddDebug();
                })
```

**Updated:** I've finally found the reason. In the Visual Studio, the output window is not the console, it is for the Debug provider. so that's why I could not see any logs inside it.
When I published the project to a folder and then execute the .exe file, it opens a console, the is the place that the console provider take affect!